# How do you get the orthogonal complement given the span?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

I know how it is done if the vectors are given but how is it done for a span?

The problem:

Let $H = span\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 1 \\
                0 & 1
            \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
                0 & 1\\
                0 & 0 
            \end{bmatrix}\right\}$. Find a basis for $H^{\bot}$.

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
c_1 \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 1 \\
                0 & 1
            \end{bmatrix} + c_2 \begin{bmatrix}
                0 & 1\\
                0 & 0 
            \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                0 & 0\\
                0 & 0 
            \end{bmatrix}\\\\
\begin{bmatrix}
                c_1 + 0c_2 & c_1 + c_2\\
                0c_1 + 0c_2 & c_1 + 0c_2
            \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
                0 & 0\\
                0 & 0 
            \end{bmatrix}\\\\
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                c_1 + 0c_2 &= 0\\
0c_1 + 0c_2 &= 0\\
c_1 + c_2 &= 0\\
c_1 + 0c_2 &= 0
            \end{bmatrix}\right\} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
1 & 0
            \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0
            \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
By performing Gram-schmidt process on to the two vectors, we get the set of the orthonormal vectors:
\begin{align*}
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
0\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}
            \end{bmatrix}\right\},
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
                -\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}\\
0\\
\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{3}\\
-\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{6}
            \end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gram-schmidt process to get a set of orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{M}_2$ with $u_1,u_2 $ as given.

Also you can denote $M$ as $a_{11}E_{11}+a_{12}E_{12}+a_{21}E_{21}+a_{22}E_{22}$, and denote 2 matrices given as column vectors $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, as the new matrix $A$,solve $A'x=0$,and orthonormalize the new basis you get.

EDIT:$A$=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  \\
1 & 1  \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
By solving $A^{T}x=0$，we get the basis of the solution space.
$\eta_1 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
-1\\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}} 
\right)$
$\eta_2 = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}} 
\right)$

Comment: As far as I know, with Gram-Schmidt process, I solve these with a given equation, then I work my way by setting them to $x_1$ to get $c_1, c_2, ... c_n$ but there is no equation given, so how do I start?

Comment: Take elementary matrices as basis and convert the problem.

Comment: Please check my attempt if it's correct.

Comment: No,you should get the solution of $A'x=0$ to get $U^{\perp}$ and use Gram-Schmidt process.

Comment: your attempt is to orthonormalize the basis of $U$, and it's not enough.

Comment: Can you show the process? I don't think I understand getting the solution of $A'x$ part.

Comment: Sorry about that I use the prime to denote transpose.

Comment: How did you get $n_1$ and $n_2$?

Comment: By solving "A^T x=0". The vectors in$U^{\perp}$ satisfy that $(\alpha_i, x)=0$

Comment: Do you mean the vectors in $H^{\bot}$?